# How to launch LLDB with a set of commands?

Tags: lldb

I want to debug an application with `lldb`. At the beginning, I want to set a few breakpoints with a set of commands. I'm aware of the `-s` option, but this somehow doesn't let me interactively debug the application after executing the commands in the file. Essentially I want to replicate the behavior of `gdb`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the way the lldb command parser sources command files, where it doesn't recognize that a command like "breakpoint command add" has switched to a new "input parser" (the one that reads and stashes away the commands but doesn't execute them, and then waits for the DONE to exit.)  The effect of this is that, if you do:

```
breakpoint command add
    some command
    some other command
    DONE
```

the input gets all messed up and things go poorly, as you have seen.  This bug is actually fixed in TOT lldb, though that hasn't made it to an official Xcode release yet.

In the meantime, there aren't any great workarounds for this.  If your breakpoint commands are simple, you can use the --one-liner option to specify them without switching to the breakpoint input parser.  Or, if you know a little Python you can make Python function breakpoint commands, import them with "script import" and tie them to the breakpoint with the -F option.